# Regression Analysis sig (2-tailed) v/s sig (1-tailed)

Tags: regression, anova

After running a Regression Analysis in IBM SPSS, the output shows sig (1-tailed) instead of sig (2-tailed). 
1) How do we obtain sig (2-tailed) output in a Regression Analysis using IBM SPSS?
2) How do we interpret the Pearson Correlation R output for a sig (1-tailed)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert one-sided into two-sided just double it.

One-sided tests are what the name implies. Your alternative hypothesis is that $\rho > 0$ (or $<$) and you are saying that however extreme it is in the other direction you are going to ignore it. Since that is often a strange thing to do you are right to seek for two-sided tests.

Comment: If R=0.75, with one tailed test, does R stay the same value (0.75) with a 2 tailed test?

Comment: Yes it is only the $p$-value which is affected.